# How to find the source url of an exception in sentry?

Tags: python, django, logging, sentry

**ENV INFO**

- DJANGO 1.8.2
- SENTRY 7.7.4
- RAVEN  5.8.1
- Installed sentry logging
  according to
  https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/integrations/django/

I am using sentry to catch the crash reports. I got an alert saying there is an exception and it displays the stacktrace clearly:

[image]

For it is a web app based on django I want to know in which url the exception is raised up. I did some searching on getsentry.com but only find that we can add **extra** in the logging module like this.

https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/learn/context/

Is there more convenient way to do this, like configure it in sentry dashboard(I thought the source url is a must-have contextual info).

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions raised internally are without URL. Only exceptions triggered by requests have URL. See sentry error screen below:

[image].